# why does scanf in while loop spam console?

Tags: c, scanf

The goal behind the following is asking the user for input until an `exit` string is entered but the preferred execution is not met because this function spams the `printf` strings and does not take user input more than one time

```
void test()
{
    int res=0;
    while (res >=0)
    {
        char buffer[1024];
        printf("Enter input: ");
        res = scanf("%[^\n]", buffer);
        printf("\n[%d]you entered: %s\n",res , buffer);
        if (strcmp(buffer, "exit") == 0)
            return ;
    }
}

int main()
{
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

How to use `scanf` so that it waits until a user inputs something?

Comment: On what character did you tell the input to *stop*, and what do you think happened to that character? Hint: It didn't just magically disappear into the ether. So what do you think happens the *next* time you ask to stop at that point again? Another hint: you're already there.

Comment: Reading "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)" might help.

Comment: One solution is to put a space at the beginning of the format string to eat the '\n' which remains in the keyboard buffer.  

`res = scanf(" %[^\n]", buffer);`